# Save data into a xml file in Adobe Flash

Tags: android, xml, flash

I have a flash application, lets call it "bee". I want Bee to save its data into an xml file in the specific directory. Check if the xml file and the directory exists or not, if exists then update it, if not then create the new one.

My .xml look like this :

```
<Achievement>
 <Coins>800</Coins>
</Achievement>
```

I want to deploy bee to Android Device. Is it possible ? how to do that ?  I would like some suggestions as to how to start the task.

Any code snippets and links will be helpful ...

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

In android we can store data in many ways, The simpler method is SharedPreference,
By using this method you can store data as Xml format,But If you deploy your flash application to android device no need of using any conventional android methods for data storage, You can use the same method followed in flash files.

Comment: What do you mean "You can use the same method followed in flash files." ??

sorry for my late reply